# how to get response in json format using php sdk from twilio sms api

Tags: php, json, twilio

I need response in json format which I am getting as

```
 class Services_Twilio_Rest_Message
```

I need the response returned after sending SMS in following json:

```
{
  "sid": "sid",
  "date_created": "Tue, 20 Oct 2015 06:01:14 +0000",
  "date_updated": "Tue, 20 Oct 2015 06:01:14 +0000",
  "date_sent": null,
  "account_sid": "AccountSid",
  "to": "+91999999999",
  "from": "+18989898989",
  "body": "I am trying to send a message having characters more than 160. But twilio allows concatenated messages upto 1600 characters length, i thought i should give it a try. So i wrote this weird message.",
  "status": "queued",
  "num_segments": "2",
  "num_media": "0",
  "direction": "outbound-api",
  "api_version": "2010-04-01",
  "price": null,
  "price_unit": "USD",
  "error_code": null,
  "error_message": null,
  "uri": "/2010-04-01/Accounts/AccountSid/Messages/SM745b97dcb56a4f9f82c52242ca3b5e92.json",
  "subresource_uris": {
    "media": "/2010-04-01/Accounts/AccountSid/Messages/SM745b97dcb56a4f9f82c52242ca3b5e92/Media.json"
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. The API returns JSON, but the PHP SDK wraps that up in objects so that it is easier to deal with in your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ricky from Twilio here.

The Services_Twilio_Rest_Message object has an [toString method](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/blob/master/Services/Twilio/Resource.php#L123-L131) that will return the json representation object. If you simply want to output the json for debugging you can just echo the response you get:

```
$message = $client->account->messages->create(array(
    "From" => "XXX-XXX-XXXX",
    "To" => "XXX-XXX-XXXX",
    "Body" => "Test message!",
));

echo $message;
```

If you need to store that string in a variable you can explicitly cast $message to a string:

```
$json = (string)$message;
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Sorry about that, in that case I may not be fully understanding your question. Is there a delta between the json the toString method is giving you vs what you'd like to have returned?

Comment: This no longer works, and should not be the accepted answer.